# Why does my highest hierarchical file not recognize the lowest hierarchical file?

Tags: c++, header, unreal-engine4

I have this weird thing going on in Unreal Engine 4, where I think I don't understand how headers work, and yet I'm pretty sure I do.

using "**->**" sign to show which **header (right of ->)** **is** **included where (left of ->)** , I have it set up as followed:

`ChessComponent.h`->`ChessBoard.h`->`ChessTile.h`->`ChessPiece.h`->`ChessDataTypes.h`->`IntVector2D.h`

```
//ChessComponent.h:

#pragma once

#include "Components/ActorComponent.h"
#include "ChessBoard.h"
#include "ChessComponent.generated.h"

UCLASS( ClassGroup=(Custom), meta=(BlueprintSpawnableComponent) )
class CHESSPLUGIN_API UChessComponent : public UActorComponent
{
    GENERATED_BODY()
public:

    UChessComponent();
    ~UChessComponent();

    UFUNCTION()
        void test(FIntVector2D testIntVector2D);
}
```

```
//ChessBoard.h:

#pragma once

#include "ChessTile.h"

class CHESSPLUGIN_API ChessBoard
{
public:

   void test(FIntVector2D testIntVector2D);
}
```

```
//ChessTile.h:

#pragma once

#include "ChessPiece.h"
#include "PawnPiece.h"
#include "BishopPiece.h"
#include "KingPiece.h"
#include "KnightPiece.h"
#include "QueenPiece.h"
#include "RookPiece.h"

class CHESSPLUGIN_API ChessTile
{
public:

FIntVector2D test{};


}
```

```
//ChessPiece.h:

#pragma once

#include "ChessDataTypes.h"
#include "ChessPluginCoreLibrary.h"

class CHESSPLUGIN_API ChessPiece
{
public:

FIntVector2D test{};
}
```

```
//ChessDataTypes.h:

#pragma once

#include "CoreMinimal.h"
#include "map"
#include "array"
#include <vector>
#include "IntVector2D.h"

class CHESSPLUGIN_API ChessDataTypes
{
};
typedef std::pair<EChesspieces, EChessColor> TChesspiece;
typedef std::map<FIntVector2D, TChesspiece> TChessTiles_Test;
```

```
//IntVector2D.h:

#pragma once

#include "CoreMinimal.h"
#include "Engine/UserDefinedStruct.h"
#include "string"
#include "iostream"
#include "IntVector2D.generated.h"

USTRUCT(BlueprintType)
struct CHESSPLUGIN_API FIntVector2D
{
    GENERATED_USTRUCT_BODY()

public:
    FIntVector2D(int32 x, int32 y)
    {
        this->x = x;
        this->y = y;
    }
    FIntVector2D()
    {
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
    }

    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite)
        int32 x;
    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite)
        int32 y;

    friend bool operator<(const FIntVector2D& l, const FIntVector2D& r)
    {
        return std::tie(l.x, l.y)
            < std::tie(r.x, r.y);
    }

    friend bool operator==(const FIntVector2D& l, const FIntVector2D& r)
    {
        return std::tie(l.x, l.y)
            == std::tie(r.x, r.y);
    }
}
```

I am capable of making an `FIntVector2D intVector{};` variable in any of the files and it is recognized by passing it on to the layer above through headers. Only in the most upper layer, being `ChessComponent.h` it doesn't recognize the `struct FIntVector2D{};`. I am unable to figure out why this is the case. I hope someone knows how to fix it other than just adding the header again in `ChessComponent.h` because that doesn't seem like good practice.

Comment: ***it doesn't recognize the struct FIntVector2D{};***  What does that mean? Do you get a compiler error? If you do please post the exact text of the error message as text.

Comment: Yes I do. I'm getting the following errors:

**Error (active) E1696** cannot open source file "ChessComponent.generated.h"   ChessComponent.h
**Error (active) E0077** this declaration has no storage class or type specifier   ChessComponent.h 
**Error**  Unrecognized type 'FIntVector2D' - type must be a UCLASS, USTRUCT or UENUM ChessComponent.h
**Error (active) E1455** member function declared with 'override' does not override a base class member CoreNet.h 
**Error** MSB3073 The command "" exited with code -1. Microsoft.MakeFile.Targets

Comment: `E0000`-numbered errors are IntelliSense heuristics. Those can be ignored if the build actually succeeds without real errors (`C0000`-numbered).

Comment: I don't want to be _that_ guy, but why are you even using `std`-library functionality here? Why aren't you using `FIntPoint`? Why aren't you forward declaring your types and only include them in the cpp files? Why aren't you using `TArray<T>` and `TMap<TKey, TValue>`? Also, ignore everything IntelliSense says when it comes to UE. Only the build matters. If it builds, it builds.

Comment: I'm pretty new to coding so any advise is welcome really. It doesn't build unless I add the header to the chessComponent and that is the main problem that I don't understand, so far it doesn't seem like anyone knows why that is the case which is the question here. **For the unreal variables vs std variables:** I had some problems in the past where non-UCLASS classes could not read unreal variables and I was unable to fix it due to inexperience mostly, so I should start trying that again. **forward declaring:** I'll read up on it. thanks.